# Can't get hash from the server

Tags: python, hash, encoding

I am currently having a problem getting hash from the server.

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

here is error:

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(url) #request
hash = hashlib.md5(data.read().decode('utf-8')).hexdigest() #
```

Actually I tried to replace decode() by encode() but it gives another error:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just remove the `.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: thank you! I thought that decode is important here, but it fix my error

Comment: Just for the understanding: `read()` of `urlopen()` returns bytes. `decode()` will covert the bytes to a unicode string. And `md5()` requires bytes as input.

Comment: good explanation! it really helps!

Comment: I compiled it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `.decode('utf-8')`.

For the understanding: `read()` of `urlopen()` returns bytes. `decode()` will covert the bytes to a unicode string. And `md5()` requires bytes as input.